# Why are mipmaps not boosting sprite performance in this 2.5D scenario?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, textures, sprite, mipmaps

I have a situation where I have loads of high-resolution bushes.

The issue is, these bushes are far too high detail and thus cause performance issues (partly because of shadows). A smooth solution to this would possibly be mipmaps, allowing the bushes to become lower resolution when further away from the camera. However, this did not work as anticipated.

Scene with mipmaps (as you can see the sprites further away are blurry):
[image]

Scene without mipmaps:
[image]

This is the performance difference.
[image]

With mipmaps

[image]

Without mipmaps

[image]

Why is there no performance increase?

Comment: Sorry, but I have a bug where I can’t see any images people post, so is it the RAM that isn’t being decreased, FPS, or CPU. Is it something else you are talking about that I have not listed?

Comment: FPS is not increasing.

Comment: Can you include your draw calls stats ? Check this link:
http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/learn-draw-call-reduction-and-make-your-games-run-superfast

Comment: Also, you might want to include a screenshot of your wireframe, current polycount on the screen, texture resolution of each bush, information on if they have active animations etc. there is too little information to really tell you anything. Mip Maps dont seem to be your solution though.

Comment: @Pfinnn I added stats for the scenarios. It's virtually the exact same. (The FPS actually hovers around 90 but the exact moment I take the screenshot it dips. But they are both at around 90)

Comment: Maybe there is no performance increase because the SpriteRenderer still contains the same amount of vertices/triangles to accommodate the higher-resolution image, so the mipmap version and the non-mipmap version both cause the same drawcalls/shadow resolution?

Comment: 737 Batches is alot of draw calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mipmaps are not the solution for your performance issue. They only reduce the texture resolution of the objects further away. The performance difference is there, but it is not what you expected.

**737** Batches is alot of draw calls batched together.

To reduce the draw calls and to gain the desired performance boost
you have several options:

- Reduce the Triangle Count. You did not show the wireframe as suggested, but what you want to do for your grass is have a simple square with 2 triangles and use the alpha mask based texture like you already did.
- Make your material more efficient: for example do not use 2 sided rendering, if you use a shader graph, reduce the amount of processing.
- Make them grass objects static and bake your lighting. as the renderer will need 1 draw call for the mesh and 1 draw call for the light, this will drastically reduce your draw calls.
- Additionally, you could also group several grass objects into clusters. Texture them with one material, as each individual material also efeccts your performance.

To understand the difference between draw calls and batches, read this:

https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/207061413-Why-are-my-batches-draw-calls-so-high-What-does-that-mean-

Very informative forum post on polycount where Joe Wilson shares some knowledge. Worth a read:
https://polycount.com/discussion/206507/the-cost-of-a-texture-draw-call-quantity-vs-resolution

Comment: I ended up going with LOD sprites instead, so that the sprite renderer creates fewer vertices.

Comment: I should mention these grass objects cannot be static, because they are SpriteRenderers - which do not support static batching.